# Bicycle trainer tyre - understanding the sizing

Tags: tire, trainer, rollers, turbo-trainer

The weather where I live is very bad sometimes. I was thinking of buying either a magnetic or fluid trainer or rollers. I read that the tyres wear out quickly on those and one should use specific tyres for indoor trainers and rollers.

I'm a little confused about the sizing. In a sticker on my rims, it says

```
ETRTO Rim size: 584 x 19C Inner Rim Width: 19C
ETRTO Recommend Tire Section Width: 28mm - 62mm
```

On my tyres there's the following

```
37-622 (700 x 37C - 28 x 1 5/8 x 1 3/8)
```

What do these mean?

The indoor trainer tyres I'm looking for have a few options:

```
26 x 1,1
700 x 23C
26 x 1,75
700 x 32C
```

Which one of these suits my rims?

Comment: The rim says 584 which to me means a 650b rim, but the number on the existing tire points to 700. Definitely something odd here. I would say the tire measurement should be the one to go for, but definitely safer to just bring in the wheel to the shop when you buy one to ensure you get the right size.

Comment: 622 iso is same as 700 and 29.  I am with Kibbee that 584 does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track buying a trainer-specific tire- trainers generate a decent amount of heat and eat tires.

Your current tire is a 700c x 37, so out of the list, I'd go for the 700 x 32. The 26 options won't fit on the rim.

Comment: As others have pointed out in the comments, theres something fishy with your labeling - the rim is labeled as a 650b, but you allegedly have a 700c tire on it... Checking with a bike shop is likely a good option.